# How to ignore a value in list?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I've a list of string and I want to ignore certain elements in that list. For example my list

```
variable domain_names = {
  type = list(string)
}

domain_names = ["foo.com","*.foo.com","*.foo2.com","bar.co.in"]

output = [ "foo.com","bar.co.in"]
```

I want to ignore anything that starts with * and create a new list out of it. How can i achieve this?

I was trying to make this module more robust to handle multiple domain names

```
locals {
  distinct_domain_name = distinct(var.domain_names)
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "main" {
  count                     = length(local.distinct_domain_name)
  domain_name               = local.distinct_domain_name[count.index]
  subject_alternative_names = [slice(var.domain_names, 1, length(var.domain_names))]
  validation_method         = var.validation_method
  tags {
    Name      = local.distinct_domain_name[count.index]
    owner     = "xxx"
    terraform = "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: This will likely require a lambda, so can we see the context of the code?

Comment: Try this `[for x in distinct(var.domain_names): x if  not contains(distinct(var.domain_names), x)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When our goal is to filter a list, the usual place to start is a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) with an `if` clause. That allows us to make a decision for each element, but raises the question of what expression to use to make that decision.

For the question of "how can we detect if a string has a particular prefix?" I think there are at least a few different ways to get that done but probably the most concise would be to use a regular expression, via [`regexall`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/regexall.html), and return true if there is at least one match:

```
length(regexall("^\\*\\.", domain_name)) > 0
```

I used `regexall` rather than `regex` here because `regex` is defined to *return an error* if there is no match -- it expects at least one -- whereas `regexall` lets us handle the zero-matches case ourselves.

Combining that with a `for` expression would give us the following:

```
[ for domain_name in var.domain_names : domain_name if length(regexall("^\\*\\.", domain_name)) > 0 ]
```

The above produces a list of the ones that *do* have `*.` as a prefix. We can negate that expression to produce the opposite subset:

```
[ for domain_name in var.domain_names : domain_name if length(regexall("^\\*\\.", domain_name)) == 0 ]
```

Comment: if you are using terraform 0.13 and encountering `Unsuitable value for left operand: number required.` while trying above solution. You will need to add [length](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/length.html) function to regexall to count the length of the string with the condition.